# Проблема с Selenium WebDriver на Firefox. Браузер обнаруживает что это бот

Tags: selenium, бот, selenium-webdriver, firefox, test-automation

Пытаюсь автоматизировать сборщик на одном из сайтов, но браузер скорее всего обнаруживает что это бот, и выдаёт ошибку.

```
options = Options()

options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)

options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")

options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpv")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
```

Такие параметры использую.
Всё равно сайт блокирует автоматизацию. Нужно логинится через куки(подгружаю через файл), и после нажимать кнопку сборщика по таймеру. Перед обновлением сайта, работало корректно. Сейчас работает, но если я вручную нажимаю. Если с браузера селена, то не даёт нажать и пишет что вы не прошли капчу (капча скорее всего скрытая, или это же просто обнаружение ботов)

Бот работает на сервере, поэтому и хеадлес.

Суть в том, что Я открываю два браузера. Один вручную просто по ярлыку, второй через вебдрайвер. Делаю те же действия, но, на обычном браузере ничего, никаких ошибок, через браузер с вебдрайвера пишет КАПЧА НЕ ПРОЙДЕНА.... Учитывая что я никакой капчи не проходил, просто логинился.

В чем может быть проблема? Мало верю что прокси помогут, так как запускал два окна с одного пк... Айпи с браузера вебдрайвера как я понимаю такие же как и у меня

Comment: сформулируйте вопрос

Comment: либо капчу нужно проходить платным сервисом,либо использовать прокси

Comment: @alex, выше описал в чём проблема точнее. Я не прохожу никаких капч при тех же действиях в своём браузере, и не смог найти капчу в коде сайта... У них наверное какой-то скрытый джс есть на проверку бота

Comment: Прокси уже попробовал?Обычно оно устраняет все скрытые препятствия

Comment: @alex мало верю что поможет. Думаешь стоить купить только ради теста? Можешь сам посмотреть пожалуйста сайт? howl.gg Каждые 25 минут появляется кнопка раздачи, нужно нажимать. С моего браузера на пк/телефоне спокойно жмётся, с бота перестало. Даже если на том же пк запускаю

Comment: Скриншот сделай ошибки при нажатии селениумом,может нужно подождать перед нажатием,а он у сразу кликает и срабатывает защита

Comment: @alex,  если я тебе скину файл для запуску, сможешь чекнуть? Задержка стоит перед кликом

Comment: @alex оно просто не даёт ошибки в коде, оно даёт ошибку именно на сайте, тип капча не пройдена